# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable while calling multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to execute the following script by using multiprocessing and queues,

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
from yahoo_finance import Share
import multiprocessing


class Stock:

    def __init__(self,symbol,q):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.q = q

    def current_value(self):
        current_price =self.q.put(float(getQuotes(self.symbol)[0]['LastTradeWithCurrency']))
        return current_price

    def fundems(self):

        marketcap = self.q.put(Share(self.symbol).get_market_cap())
        bookvalue = self.q.put(Share(self.symbol).get_book_value())
        dividend = self.q.put(Share(self.symbol).get_dividend_share())
        dividend_paydate = self.q.put(Share(self.symbol).get_dividend_pay_date())
        dividend_yield = self.q.put(Share(self.symbol).get_dividend_yield())

        return marketcap, bookvalue, dividend, dividend_paydate, dividend_yield



def main():
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    Stock1 = Stock('aapl', q) 


    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = Stock1.current_value(), args = (q,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = Stock1.fundems(), args = (q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    while q.empty() is False:
        print q.get()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting the output as the following:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
139.52
732.00B
25.19
2.28
2/16/2017
1.63
```

Here I see that I am able to get the output which I wanted, but there was  an error before that which is kind a making me confused.

Can anyone please help me understand the concept here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `target` should be an uncalled function, you're calling the function in the parent process and trying to launch a `Process` with the results of the call as the target. Change:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = Stock1.current_value(), args = (q,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = Stock1.fundems(), args = (q,))
```

to:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Stock1.current_value)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Stock1.fundems)
```

`q` is removed as an argument because the object was constructed with `q`, and uses its own state to access it, it doesn't receive it as an argument to each method.

Comment: Nope.. it did not work. It threw me the following error,

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: fundems() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
    self.run()

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: current_value() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = Stock1.current_value)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = Stock1.fundems)

Comment: This gave me the answer

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger

Comment: @Bhargav for future reference, whenever you get a new error, you should post a new question

Comment: sure :) @Code-Apprentice